# English pronoun for Person as a subject

Tags: genderless-pronouns

what pronoun substitutes the noun -person- for this sentence, please:

ie: when a person sees something, x[the person] should call the police.

Comment: "he", "she", or "they".  But you should add more detail to the question to explain why this is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, it's ('singular') **they**. It's not everywhere accepted, so in some manuals 'he or she' is recommended instead, especially for formal usage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: 'he or she' are not enough nowadays: you've got to add 'it'. There is much to be said in favour of the concise and humorous 's/h/it', don't you think, because it does happen... it IS happening.